# Linear algebra - Prove that for any isomorphism there is an "identity basis(?)"

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-space-isomorphism

I'd appreciate if you could help me with this question.
What I thought about so far is showing that for any basis $B$, we know that $[T]_B$ is invertible so there are $k$ elementary matrices such that $E^k*...*E^1*[T]_B=I$.

I'm not sure if it's a good direction. Here is the question:

**Let $V$ be a vector space over $F$. Prove that for any isomorphism $T : V \rightarrow F^n$, there exists a basis $B$ for $V$ such that $T=Is_B$, meaning $T(v)=[v]_B$**

Note: if you see a solution I'd be happy if you could write a hint in addition to your solution, so i can try it myself first.

Also, I'm not a native english speaker so if anything is not clear please tell me and I'll fix it.

Comment: Hint: inverse to $T$

Comment: Unfortunately i still don't get it. 
Would be happy if someone could post a solution

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Let $B=\{ v_1,..., v_n \}$ be the basis you seek. Since $T(v)=[v]_B$ for all $v$ yoou must have for $v=v_i \in B$:
$$T(v_i)=[v_i]_{B}$$

Now use the fact that 
$$[v_i]_B=(0,0,..., 0,1 ,0,..0)=e_i$$

Comment: I don't get it, why does $T(v_i)=[v_i]_B$?
Isn't that what we're trying to prove for some B?

Comment: @reggiN What are the coordinates of $v_1$ with respect to the basis $\{ v_1,v_2,.., v_n \}$?

Comment: Yes I understand that, but I don't see how it relates to $T(v_i)$. $B$ is just some random basis so who's to say $T(v_i)$ isn't (1,01,...,1,0,1) or anything else?
I have already found a solution, But I'd like you to clarify why the left equality is true if you can.

Comment: @reggiN Because the exercise asks you to have for all $v$  $$T(v)=[v]_B$$ What does this tell you when $v=v_i$?

Comment: Can the downvoter explain? And the request to delete the answer?